# Java - PocketSphinx Android doesn't run when exported

Tags: java, android, cmusphinx

I'm using PocketSphinx Android in my app. It runs as expected when i'm debugging using eclipse. However, when i export to apk it using eclipse, the voice recognizer doesn't run. I'm not getting any error though.

Comment: Run `adb logcat` from the terminal to see the device log. Chances are you'll find the cause of the problem there.

Comment: IOException: sync/assets.lst

Comment: I've replied you on the corresponding GitHub issue page. Please, keep the conversation in a single place - here or on GitHub.

Comment: Yeh sure. I have closed the issue on Github. Just updating on stackoverflow https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/issues/2